# Want a report for two separate category rows from ireport crosstab

Tags: mysql, jasper-reports, ireport

This is the query I'm going to use

```
select monthNmae, monthID, achievement , target from salse
```

Above query returns the following result

```
month  | monthID | achievement  | target
jan      1         12              10
feb      2         56              20
mar      3         9               20
.        .         .               .
.        .         .               .
.        .         .               .
.        .         .               .
dec     12        70               68
```

I want a table from Jasper report like

```
month          jan    feb    mar ............... Dec 
Achievement    12     56     9   ..............  70
target         10     26     20  ..............  68
```

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a query to get the data in the format that you want.  In MySQL, you can use an aggregate function and a `CASE` statement:

```
select src_col as month, 
  sum(case when month = 'jan' then value end) `jan`,
  sum(case when month = 'feb' then value end) `feb`,
  sum(case when month = 'mar' then value end) `mar`,  -- add other months here
  sum(case when month = 'dec' then value end) `dec`   
from
(
  select month, monthid, achievement value, 'achievement' src_col
  from salse
  union all
  select month, monthid, target value, 'target' src_col
  from salse
) src
group by src_col
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/88960/5)